# Toggling play / pause button using a directive in ionic / angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to toggle a play / pause button in ionic using a directive, based on the value of

```
$scope.autoplay
```

In the HTML I have the button element:

```
<playbtn></playbtn>
```

The button is an Ionic icon.

Play button:  `<i class="ion-ios-play"></i>`

Pause button:  `<i class="ion-ios-pause"></i>`

How should this directive be changed to toggle the icon ?

```
.directive('playbtn', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<i class=""></i>',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
      if(scope.autoplay == 'true') {
       //show pause button

      } else {
       //show play button
      }
    };    
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) like so:

```
.directive('playbtn', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {autoplay:'='},
      template: '<i ng-class="{\'ion-ios-play\': autoplay, \'ion-ios-pause\': !autoplay}"></i>'
    }
})
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zzwognt/1/).

Comment: I set your solution up [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilbiscuit/8zzwognt/)  but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was looking for how to do this in react but couldn't find much, here is solution I've found/figured out

```
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
const play = () => { 
    if (playing == true){
      // stop and start again
      player.playbackManager.pause(); 
      setPlaying(false);
    }else{
      // play 
      player.playbackManager.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };


  return (
   <div>
   <div className="controller-bar"> 
        <IonButton component="span" onClick={play}>
           
 {playing ? ( <PlayArrow />  ) : (   <Pause/> )}
        </IonButton> 
  </div>
  );
}
```